# I have an accordion in my webpage, but adding any other javascript is breaking the accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an accordion in the left sidebar, with links which should open specific content in the right sidebar. I cannot post everything here but you can see it at http://iwarchitects.com/company

now, if anyone clicks the link "list item one" in publications tab, he should see the content showing the list of publications in the right sidebar.

I tried using jquery, but it all messed up like in this URL : http://iwarchitects.com/test

I want to show a image in the right sidebar for "company","history" and "awards" tab, and show a corresponding list of publications for the "publication" tab.

The corresponding CSS and HTML for these pages can be seen by "view page source"

Comment: You realize you have several images, a font and a `test.css` stylesheet not loading, right? In Google Chrome press `Ctrl+Shift+J` to open developer console. In IE press F12. In Firefox you have 2 options. `Ctrl+Shift+K` will open `web-console` whereas `Ctrl+Shift+J` will open an error console that will be nice enought o show you CSS it's not compatible with or having issues with. I assume this is because Firefox's engine will (and i've seen it) break on CSS and throw JS out the window.

Comment: Your site is blocked from where I am (at work) can you please show some of your HTML and jQuery?

Comment: Sorry ... I made the changes few minutes ago...The CSS and test page are loading correctly now....but the problem of showing content to show corresponding content exists even now. I hope you can please please help me

Answer (score 0):

first your test.css file is not getting loaded on page http://iwarchitects.com/stylesheets/test.css

Comment: you have two version of jquery on your page one is v1.9.1 and another one is v1.10.1. remove one of them.

Comment: Yes... I removed the older one. The accordion is working properly.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to load corresponding content in the right side bar?

Comment: from where your content will come, its dynamic or static ? also if you accordion is working you may vote the answer.